# How to define a new frame option for headless - no title or headline (but not plain) - slides?

Tags: beamer, headline

I am looking to add an option to a frame such that this functions as expected, and produces a slide without a headline or frametitle, but does have a footline.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{headless}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[headless]{Headless Frame}
    This frame should not have a headline.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Regular Frame}
    This frame retains its headline.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is my current code, which does not function:

```
% beamerthemeheadless.sty
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeheadless}

\mode<presentation>

\newif\ifbeamer@headless
\beamer@headlessfalse


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{
  \ifbeamer@headless
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 
  \fi
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{frame}{
  \ifbeamer@headless
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default] 
    \beamer@headlessfalse 
  \fi
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{headless}[true]{%
  \beamer@headlesstrue
}

\mode<all>
```

I have also tried the following, based off how the focus theme defines plain.

```
% beamerthemeheadless.sty
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeheadless}

\providebool{beamer@headless}
\define@key{beamerframe}{headless}[true]{%
    \begingroup%
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{c}%
    \centering%

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same approach as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1162#a1369:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{headless}{}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default]}
\define@key{beamerframe}{headless}[true]{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[headless]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Regular Frame}
    This frame retains its headline.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[headless]
    \frametitle{Headless Frame}
    This frame should not have a headline.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Regular Frame}
    This frame retains its headline.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not function, and it does not follow my MWE. I am unable to upload images in the comments, so I will update the main post with the screenshot.

I should clarify, the frametitle should not be visible on a headless frame, nor should a normal frame say "normal headline".

Comment: @NictraSavios Works fine for me. And it seems to work as well in the screenhot you added to your question. The regular frame shows the headline text at the top left, the headless frame does not has this text.

Comment: should clarify, the frametitle should not be visible on a headless frame, nor should a normal frame say "normal headline".

Comment: If you want to hide the frametitle, why do you ask about removing the headline?

Comment: Well, if you want to remove the frametitle, redefine the frametitle template instead of the headline.

Comment: Appologies, a misunderstanding on my part from the language used in my day job. In newspapers, the headline is the title.

Comment: Edited, however I'm wondering why you specify a frametitle if you don't want a frametitle. For the headline, such an option would have been understandable, for the title not so much.

Comment: Thank you! Marked as the correct answer.